# Methylation of nitroalkanes with diazomethane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nitro-compounds

It is known that diazomethane can methylate various compounds with acidic hydrogens. Diazomethane is most well-known for the efficient synthesis of methyl esters from carboxylic acids. Clayden, Greeves, & Warren (2012) mention that it can also methylate phenols ($\ce {pK_a = 10}$), but not straight-chain alcohols ($\ce {pK_a = 16}$). The latter not being acidic enough. I was just wondering if nitroalkanes ($\ce {pK_a = 10}$) would be able to be methylated by diazomethane?

**Reference**

Clayden, J., Greeves, N., & Warren, S. (2012). Organic Chemistry (2nd ed.). New York : Oxford University Press Inc.

Comment: Never seen this reaction - which doesn't mean there are not examples though

Comment: That pKa value looks wrong to me, for simple nitroalkanes. I'm sure it is substantially higher for nitromethane, eg. ca. 17.

Comment: @OrganicChemistryExplained I am referring to the pka in water.

Comment: @OrganicChemistryExplained According to Clayden's, pka of nitromethane is indeed 10.

Comment: OK, it looks like the ~10 value may be in water, although I haven't been able to find the original ref, whereas the pKa is 17.2 in DMSO - JACS 1975, 97(24), 7006. Like @Waylander, I haven't seen this reaction. I suspect that if it is acidic enough in the right solvent to treat with diazomethane, it give O-methylation rather than C-methylation, and that O-methyl product may readily hydrolyse on workup or attempts at purification. Interesting question!